# Vagrant Won't Recognize Python latest version

Tags: python, windows, vagrant

I'm trying to install praw through vagrant but it says:

```
praw requires Python '>3.5.3' but the running Python is 2.7.17
```

When I have the latest version `3.9.6`. Full cmd:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ cd /vagrant/

vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ sudo pip install praw

The directory '/home/vagrant/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/home/vagrant/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Collecting praw

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/51/9d049faaf6c45d9c600c8a5dac5bd30d2333653a5acaf4ac3d0bf572c610/praw-7.1.0.tar.gz (21.3MB)

100% |████████████████████████████████| 21.3MB 27kB/s

praw requires Python '>3.5.3' but the running Python is 2.7.17
```

Comment: You have both python versions on your computer. Type `which -a python` to see them. Or try `pip3` instead of `pip`, maybe that'll be enough.

Comment: sudo: pip3: command not found. it didn't work. vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: fixed it: sudo apt-get install -y python3-praw. thank you